# OpenLDAP peername.ip ACL not working for subnets

Tags: ldap, openldap, access-control-list

I have the following ACL stored in my `/etc/openldap/slapd.conf` file:

```
access to dn.regex="^([^,]+,)?ou=(groups|addressbook),dc=ldap$"
      by dn.exact="cn=directory,ou=users,dc=ldap" peername.ip="172.30.253.4" read
```

This allows the device with IP 172.30.253.4 to access the addressbook and it seems to work perfectly. However, when I change this to a subnet rather than a single IP address, nothing is able to connect. The following is the ACL rule I would like to use:

```
access to dn.regex="^([^,]+,)?ou=(groups|addressbook),dc=ldap$"
      by dn.exact="cn=directory,ou=users,dc=ldap" peername.ip="172.30.253.0/24" read
```

I have also tried `172.30.253.1/24` and numerous other subnets and nothing within that subnet is able to connect.

The version I'm using is: OpenLDAP: slapd 2.4.59 (Mar  8 2023 13:33:05)

Comment: A quick search suggests it should it be `peername.regex=172\.30\.253\..*`

Comment: @Bib that doesn't seem to work. I also tried `peername.ip=172\.30\.253\..*` and tried putting quotes around it like I did above to no avail.